# circleci 2.0 can't find awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, circleci

I'm using circleCI 2.0 and they can't find aws but their [documents](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/build-image-trusty/#awscli) clearly say that aws is installed in default

when I use this circle.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/rian
    docker:
        - image: node:boron
    steps:
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: Pre-Dependencies
            command: mkdir ~/rian/artifacts
        - restore_cache:
            keys: 
              - rian-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
              - rian-{{ .Branch }}
              - rian-master
        - run:
            name: Install Dependencies
            command: yarn install
        - run:
            name: Test
            command: |
              node -v
              yarn run test:ci
        - save_cache:
            key: rian-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            paths:
              - "~/.cache/yarn"
        - store_artifacts:
            path: ~/rian/artifacts
            destination: prefix
        - store_test_results:
            path: ~/rian/test-results
        - deploy:
            command: aws s3 sync ~/rian s3://rian-s3-dev/ --delete
```

following error occurs:

```
/bin/bash: aws: command not found
Exited with code 127
```

so if I edit the code this way

```
    - deploy:
        command: |
          apt-get install awscli
          aws s3 sync ~/rian s3://rian-s3-dev/ --delete
```

then i get another kind of error:

```
Reading package lists... Done


Building dependency tree       


Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package awscli
Exited with code 100
```

Anyone knows how to fix this???

Comment: *"I'm using circleCI 2.0 and they can't find aws but their [documents](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/build-image-trusty/#awscli) clearly say..."* - stop right there and look at the URL. You're using Circle 2.0 but reading Circle 1.0 documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The document you are reading is for CircleCI 1.0 and for 2.0 is here:

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/

In CircleCI 2.0, you can use your favorite Docker image. The image you are currently setting is `node:boron`, which does not include the aws command.

- https://hub.docker.com/_/node/
- https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/14681db8e89c0493e8af20657883fa21488a7766/6.10/Dockerfile

If you just want to make it work for now, you can install the aws command yourself in `circle.yml`.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y awscli
```

However, to take full advantage of Docker's benefits, it is recommended that you build a custom Docker image that contains the necessary dependencies such as the aws command.

You can write your custom aws-cli Docker image something like this:

```
FROM circleci/python:3.7-stretch

ENV AWS_CLI_VERSION=1.16.138
RUN sudo pip install awscli==${AWS_CLI_VERSION}
```

Comment: Do they have a docker Image that has that? Or at list is there any way to cache aws-cli to save build and deployment time?

Comment: At the time of writing, AWS nor CircleCI provide official aws-cli Docker image. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3553 https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3291

Comment: @Avivbuen I've added a sample Dockerfile. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue when deploying to AWS lambda functions and pushing files to S3 bucket. Finally solved it and then built a docker image to save time in installing the AWS CLI every time. Here is a link to the image and the repo!

https://github.com/wilson208/circleci-awscli

https://hub.docker.com/r/wilson208/circleci-awscli/

Fire a PR in or open an issue if you need anything added to the image and I will get to it when I can.

Edit:

Also, checkout the readme on github for examples of deploying a package to Lambda or pushing files to S3